# Why does the number of bytes read from serial port cap at a certain number?

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I'm reading serial data at 250Hz from serial port. (I'm using a USB-serial adapter if that's relevant). Each sample is 26 bytes (tab delimited columns and lines are terminated with newline operators.) I'm using baudrate 115200. I have played around with the max buffer length to read, and in most cases I end up getting 3968(around 153 samples) bytes at a time. I have printed out the samples to confirm that the samples aren't dropped. I don't understand why it always reads ~153 samples at a time. Ideally, I would like to read fewer samples often: something like 10 samples at a time, thus giving me a faster refresh rate and reading more "real-time".

So far, I tried lowering the max buffer length, it adds more delay in reading the port, because I keep getting data even after I have stopped sending data.
The following question seems relevant but I don't understand why it's a "non-issue". 
[Stange Behavior of the Serial Port Input Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314100/stange-behavior-of-the-serial-port-input-buffer)

```
#define MAX_DATA_LENGTH 11520

SerialPort::SerialPort(char *portName)
{
...
            dcbSerialParameters.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
            dcbSerialParameters.ByteSize = 8;
            dcbSerialParameters.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
            dcbSerialParameters.Parity = NOPARITY;
            dcbSerialParameters.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
...

}


int SerialPort::readSerialPort(char *buffer, unsigned int buf_size)
{
    DWORD bytesRead;
    unsigned int toRead;

    ClearCommError(this->handler, &this->errors, &this->status);

    if (this->status.cbInQue > 0){
        if (this->status.cbInQue > buf_size){
            toRead = buf_size;
        }
        else toRead = this->status.cbInQue;
    }

    if (ReadFile(this->handler, buffer, toRead, &bytesRead, NULL)) return bytesRead;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
  SerialPort arduino(port_name);

  std::string temp_buffer;
  std::string msg;

  while (arduino.isConnected()){

    memset(&incomingData[0], 0, sizeof(incomingData));

    //Check if data has been read or not
    int read_result = arduino.readSerialPort(incomingData, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);

    //prints out data
    if(read_result > 0){

        cout << "Bytes read = " << read_result << endl;
        std::string inData(incomingData);
        inData = temp_buffer + inData;

        int end_idx = inData.rfind('\n');
        if(end_idx > 0){
            msg = inData.substr(0, end_idx+1);
            temp_buffer = inData.substr(end_idx);
        }
        else{
            msg = inData;
        }
    }
    //wait a bit
    Sleep(1);
  }
}
```

When I set the max buffer length high, I noticed that I'm getting all the samples, with minimal delay between data generation on the sending side and reading the port. When I lower that, the delay keeps building up.

EDIT: I printed out cbInQue, and turns out, it's mostly zero and gets 3968 bytes at a time. So there isn't a continuous flow of bytes coming in but rather a batch of samples at a time. Is this just the property of the serial device or is there something I can do? When I read this in putty, it's also not continuous, it looks as if the data is being update every few milliseconds.

EDIT: I changed the latency timer value of the COM port from the device manager. The default is 16ms, I changed it to 2ms and now I'm emptying the cbInQue buffer as I go and it doesn't wait to accumulate till 3968 bytes. Reading has definitely become faster. With my buffer size restricted to 500, I'm reading all of the cbInQue every time.

Comment: Note that if `this->status.cbInQue > 0` is false `toRead` will be left uninitialized.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Good catch, but that still wouldn't fix the issue. If there is no data in the buffer, it doesn't matter if I read nothing.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks! Although, arduino is just the name of the port because I'm using a snippet from other code. I'm not actually reading data from an arduino.

Comment: "Why does the number of bytes read from serial port cap at a certain number?"  Probably somewhere in the communications chain there is a buffer which is chunking the I/O to that size.

Comment: @ni5arg Beware the uninitialized values have indeterminate value. This is distinct from having some unknowable but fixed value. Trying to get that value is undefined behavior. Calling `ReadFile` with an uninitialized `toRead` can't be waved away by saying that `toRead` won't read anything anyway. First, it might receive data in the mean time. Second, that argument is taken by value, so the simple fact of calling the function tries to copy that value which is undefined behavior. It makes no difference at all that the function might not use that argument.

Comment: @ni5arg It seems you read slower that data arrived. So when you read there is already about 3968 bytes in queue (`cbInQue`) that have ready to read. Do you know how many bytes sent from serial device, for example, in one second, and how many times you can execute the read operation in one second?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You are correct. I added toRead=0 in else condition.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT The serial device is set to 250Hz and each sample is 26 bytes, giving me 6656 bytes/second. As for the second part of your question, I would like to read as often as possible but it's constrained by the number of instructions in the loop. Currently, with the buffer size greater than 4000 bytes, I'm reading 153 samples at once, so I guess I'm reading every 0.6 seconds. Of course, my goal is to bring this time down to around 0.1 seconds.

Comment: @ni5arg Set smaller buffer size and remove `Sleep(1);`.